# Can Mercurial repositories safely be moved/renamed/etc.?

Tags: mercurial, rename

Can I move the directory a local Mercurial repository is contained in without breaking it, or does it know where it lives and expect it to live there forever?  (Coming from SVN with its switch/relocate requirements for moving local repos.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, yes.  You can move the .hg repository folder and then pull a new copy of your source.

Comment: You can move `.hg` or the directory below it. The only thing that might break are the paths defined in `.hg/hgrc` if they are relative.

Comment: THAT was the question? Seriously?